# Gaze Detection using OpenCV - Help me find location of eyes on the screen

Tags: android, windows, opencv, eye-tracking

I am working on a project where I need a user's gaze (location where the user is looking at on the screen). Of course, this doesn't need to be highly accurate since I am looking to use the inbuilt webcam on a laptop. Initially I am trying to figure out how I can make this work on a Windows laptop. Later on I will move on to mobile devices - android tablets possibly.

Most examples help in detecting the pupil quite accurately, but I couldn't find anything that actually shows the projection of the eye movement/location on the screen. I have researched a lot on OpenCV and this is what I plan to use, but I really need help figuring out the location (pixels) on screen.

I want to use the location on screen, to fire an event. For eg. if a user gazes at a button on the screen, it would fire its event.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could find out the pupil, you should be able to track the location of the eye on the screen, what is your problem?

Comment: @StereoMatching, can you please clarify how the pupil center can be mapped to the gazing point at the screen? All the resources I found don't explain that in a clear way. Thank you.

Comment: @Dania My mistake, I did not read the questions carefully and though it was easy, this is a hard problem. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @StereoMatching It's ok, thanks.